# Controlador del scaffold, redireccionar a varias vistas

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo una pequeña duda con respecto a la parte de los controladores en una sitio web que estoy haciendo de edicion de imagenes. que se basa en que el usuario sube la imagen, luego de presionar el boton lo redirige a la parte de recorte mandando siempre la imagen como parametro para editarla, luego lo redirige a la parte de edicion y por ultimo la parte de escribir texto, pero por alguna extraña razon en la parte de edicion que llame a esa vista :et, cuando el usuario pulsa el boton de guardar, guarda la imagen pero no pasa a la siguiente vista que es la de Texto. estoy intentando con elsif pero no pasa al segundo elsif. alguien podria orientarme un poco de como hacerlo mejor? GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Comment: es importante que te registres en el sitio así te enterás cuando te respondan y podés ajustar tu pregunta para que sea respondida.

Comment: En la medida de lo posible copiá el código en la pregunta en vez de usar una imagen (que es más difícil de citar). Echale una mirada a http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting para formatear la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Por un lado `elsif` al igual que `if` requiere una condición, que no estás escribiendo. Esa condición es necesaria para definir cuando debería entrar en el primer `elsif` y cuando en el segundo.

Por último, te recomendaría en vez de utilizar condiciones e ifs para definir que hacer en el controlador, usar distintas [rutas](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) y distintas acciones, como:

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # codigo para subir la imagen
    redirect to cortar_imagen_path(@imagen)
  end

  def cortar
    # codigo para cortar la imagen
    redirect to agregar_texto_imagen_path(@imagen)
  end

  def agregar_texto
    ...
  end
end
```